# What are the fees for making CPI calls

Tags: transactions, cpi, fees

Am I correct in assuming that the fees are forever 0.000005 unless factors such as local fee markets come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think making a cpi doesn't affect tx fees. It's just as if you included another instruction in your transaction.